# No database selected GAE

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I amusing cloudSQL and I keep getting this error "No database selected" when I deploy my website into production.

The dump that I uploaded to cloudsql has the line "USE mydb" i have to my a db call  for "use mydb" every any query works.

Anyone know why? or how to fix it

```
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2739)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2149)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2313)
```

Comment: Post your production and development database connection code.

Answer (score 2):

Either set the database as part of the jdbc connection string, like `jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name/YOUR_DATABASE_NAME`, or switch to it with [Connection.setCatalog()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog-java.lang.String-). As mentioned on the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) you cannot use `USE db` syntax with MySQL via JDBC.